# How can I set environment variables for GUI apps in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, java, environment-variables, gui, osx-mavericks

I've been struggling to get an app to run in OS X Mavericks. I finally was able to get it to run by drilling into the .app bundle and running the shell script directly. It seems that JAVA_HOME needed to be set. So I set it in my .profile in the shell, and everything works fine.

However, if I want to simply click the icon in the dock, it won't run. My guess is that this is because JAVA_HOME is not set globally. Since I'm not running the app directly from the shell, OS X doesn't know what JAVA_HOME is. It just keeps looking.

In previous versions of OS X, it seems that environment variables could be set for GUI apps by simply adding them to /etc/launchd.conf. This file doesn't seem to exist in Mavericks. How can I set a global environment variable that will work for GUI apps in Mavericks?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`/etc/launchd.conf` has never existed by default, but it does still work in 10.9.

1. Run for example `sudo nano /etc/launchd.conf`.
2. Add a line like `setenv JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`. (I don't know what `JAVA_HOME` should actually be set to though.)
3. Either restart or run `launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf; sudo launchctl < /etc/launchd.conf` and relaunch processes.

`launchctl export` prints variables exported by the user launchd process and `sudo launchctl export` prints variables exported by the root launchd process.

This method can also be used to set a default path. For example I have added this line to `/etc/launchd.conf`:

`setenv PATH /Users/lauri/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/libexec:/usr/texbin`

(I used `/Users/lauri/bin` instead of `~/bin` because `~/bin` would be `/var/root/bin` for programs run as root.)

Comment: +1 for explaining how to get changes in `/etc/launchd.conf` without restarting the system.
For configuring the PATH environment variable files in `/etc/paths.d/` should be used.

Comment: Actually, `/etc/launchd.conf` doesn't work anymore after 10.10

Comment: @OleGG this remains a pain on Mac even today on Ventura :( no clear descriptions anywhere as to how we can set environment variables system wide.

Answer (score 0):

Launchd.conf is not working/usable any further since Mac OS 10.10.

Correct way to achieve this now is through LaunchAgent scripts that get loaded at startup time. Since these scripts are horrendously tedious ( personal opinion :), I prefer using .bash_profile and automatically creating/updating these scripts.

Try this SO answer for an easier way to achieve this from your .bash_profile. Hopefully this will save you the few hours I spent trying to figure it out ( again ) for my new Mac M2

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385934/setting-environment-variables-via-launchd-conf-no-longer-works-in-os-x-yosemite